# What does `[]` mean in `setState`?

Tags: reactjs

What does `[]` mean in `setState` ?

```
this.setState({
    [people.name]:e.name
})
```

I can't find the answer on the Internet or in the book.I need help.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a javascript thing. Its computed property, you can give an expression or variable inside it and it will be evaluated as key.

```js
var a = {
  [3*4]: 1
}
console.log(a)
```

Comment: so,`a.[3*4]=1`?Is that what you mean?　　And `[people.name]:e.name`　does that mean assigning the "name" attribute to "people"?

Comment: if `people.name = "foo"`, `[people.name]: e.name` is equal to `"foo": e.name`

Comment: Oh,Isee.Thank you very much.